# When binding together a list of csv tables with purrr as dataframe i want to include a tag column conditional on a string in each csv

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, conditional-statements, purrr

I am binding togeter participant raw data from 33 csv files with the following code

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '*.csv', recursive = TRUE)

result <- purrr::map_df(filenames, read.csv, .id = 'id')
```

This works great. Now I need to to include a tag per participant(csv) in the final dataframe to make clear in which of several randomized conditions they were in.
I want to make it conditional on the first word in my first column of each .csv, as each participant got one of several randomized sequences of words.

I thought of something with `ifelse()` but not sure how to include this is in above code. I am a total R noob, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should achieve what you're looking for:

```r
result <- lapply(result, function(x) { x$tag <- x[1, 1]; x })

do.call(rbind, result)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me `Error in x[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions`
I am confused, because my list object is 'filenames' and 'result' is the already the aggregated dataframe. Should't I apply the lapply function to the list of csv? Thanks again!

Comment: Resolved it. Just had to create the right list object. Worked like a charm thank you!

`
result = lapply(filenames, read.csv)

lapply(result, function(x) { x$tag = x[1,1]; x })
`